# change react component typing base on a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a React component named text that among other things allow to change the tag that's going to be rendered.

```js
export interface TextProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  children: ReactNode;
  as?: React.ElementType;
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use a `time` element like this:

```
<Text as="time" dateTime="2018-07-07">
  July 7
</Text>
```

But the TS compiler complains about `Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextProps'`

I even try to use `interface TextProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLTimeElement>` but I still get the same error.

I honestly don't know how to get type safety on this kind of components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `as` to support any built-in HTML element, we can make use of the `JSX.IntrinsicElements` interface, which maps HTML tag names to their props.

```
type IntrinsicProps = {
  [K in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]: JSX.IntrinsicElements[K] & { as: K; }
}[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]
```

This mapped type `IntrinsicProps` provides a union of all valid pairings of props and `as`.  We need to add one more thing which is whatever prop types are expected if the optional `as` prop is not provided.  That depends on what tag you are using as the default.

```
type TextProps = IntrinsicProps | ( HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> & { as?: never } )
```

You can add `children` to the props or type the component using `React.FC` which adds `children` automatically.

```
const Text: React.FC<TextProps> = (props) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

Now you can add `dateTime` as a prop, but only if your `as` type supports it!

This works:

```
<Text as="time" dateTime="2018-07-07">July 7</Text>
```

But this gives an error "Property `'dateTime'` does not exist on type `IntrinsicAttributes & ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & { ...; } & { ...; }`"

```
<Text as="div" dateTime="2018-07-07">July 7</Text>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/GNlQrm)

Comment: It doesn't complain if we don't pass as prop. Can we put a default as prop and that should be considered if we don't pass as a prop?
For eg. <Text dateTime="2018-07-07">July 7</Text>, In this, I haven't passed as prop. Therefore, It should consider as prop's value as div and should complain about the dateTime prop.

 <Text dateTime="2018-07-07">July 7</Text> // should complain
 <Text>July 7</Text> // shoudn't complain

Answer (score 0):

Try `React.TimeHTMLAttributes` type.

```ts
export interface TextProps extends React.TimeHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  children: ReactNode;
  as?: React.ElementType;
}
```